# Question about the degree of the composition of two isogenies

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogeny

I'm reading a paper about isogeny based cryptography and I came across a sentence that seems to imply that for separable isogenies $\phi$ and $\psi$, the following holds: deg$(\phi \circ \psi)=$ deg$(\phi)$deg$(\psi)$. I can't seem to figure out why this is true, or if it is even true. Any clarification would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try it this way: if an isogeny has degree $d$, then each point in the codomain has $d$ elements in its preimage. Then it ought to be clear why degrees multiply as you wish. (I’m pretty sure that the hypothesis of separability is unnecessary, if you use a different (more algebraic) definition of degree.)

Comment: @Lubin Great thanks so much! In reality, the paper I'm working with only cares about spearable isogenies, so the only "definition" of degree I know is stricly for separable isogenies: deg$\phi$=#ker$\phi$. Either way thank you so much for your help!